# Sys.argv order based on extension

Tags: python

I am currently development one script which receives three arguments via cmd containing inputs for performing an specific task. So, to illustrate it looks something like this on cmd to run the script:

```
python run.py arg1.yaml arg2.json C:\Users\JohnDoe\Documents
```

The extensions in this fictitious examples are just made up for the sake of explanation, in reality I am using other files. So, in order to run run.py I have a main function foo receive the system arguments as argument:

```
input1 = os.getcwd() + f"\{sys.argv[1]}"
input2 = os.getcwd() + f"\{sys.argv[2]}"
input3 = os.getcwd() + f"\{sys.argv[3]}"

foo(input1, input2, input3)
```

Observe that I set `input1`, `input2` and `input3` according to their position, which is something that I want to avoid. What I want to achieve is: I am setting the inputs according to the order in which the user wrote. I would like for example, to be able to set `input1`,`input2` and `input3` correctly in case that the user messed up and swapped the orders, like this:

```
python run.py arg2.json C:\Users\JohnDoe\Documents arg1.yaml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the extension:

```
for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
    if arg.endswith('.yaml'):
        input1 = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), arg)
    elif arg.endswith('.json'):
        input2 = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), arg)
    else:
        input3 = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), arg)
```

It might be easier to use a dictionary to ensure all three inputs are given. There is also a matter of ensuring there are no two arguments with the same end.